# mssparkutils on local python environment

Tags: python-3.x, azure-synapse

I'm building some reusable libraries to use in Azure synapse. And these libraries need mssparkutils, built-in synapse library. Is it possible to install this library/module on local python environment?

Comment: As mssparkutils is a builtin package, it cannot be installed on local python environment.

Comment: Valid question and valid answer, this library doesn't have any sense outside the synapse enviroment, nevertheless, what if we build libraries that use this functionality to operate? how can the building and testing flow of this libraries be implemented properly?